# What is a trigger ledger?

Tags: stellar-core

While my node is catching up with the rest of the nodes, I see this in `stellar-core -c info`:

```
"status" : [
   "Catching up: Waiting for trigger ledger: 20194405/20194433, ETA: 140s",
   "Publishing 832 queued checkpoints [20140799-20194367]: Succeded: prepare-snapshot"
]
```

What is a trigger ledger?

Answer (score 2):

Skimming the code and taking my best guess, I believe that a ledger closed is being attempted, but the ledger manager identifies that there are missing ledgers. It buffers the ledger it just received and initiates a catch-up of the missing, preceding ledgers.

This process happens when [the ledger manager identifies that it is out of sync during a close ledger attempt](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/cb61d6b09b0088989c6c3a23d55d97ef5ce1001d/src/ledger/LedgerManagerImpl.cpp#L484-L489).

In your question, the log message indicates that `20194405` is the head of the your known ledger history and `20194433` is the ledger just closed. It estimates ~2 mins to fill in the gaps.

Here's the [log message](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/cb61d6b09b0088989c6c3a23d55d97ef5ce1001d/src/ledger/LedgerManagerImpl.cpp#L612-L614):

```
fmt::format("Waiting for trigger ledger: {}/{}, ETA: {}s",
            lastReceivedLedgerSeq, mCatchupTriggerLedger, eta.count());
```